# Remove entry based on the value of first column

Tags: linux, shell

If 3549,2152,4701 in first column then remove the entry:

sample data:

```
18106|1.0.4.0/22
3549|1.0.10.0/24
5413|1.0.0.0/16
2152|1.4.0.0/16
3549|1.0.8.0/22
4701|1.0.0.0/8
```

Expedted output:

```
18106|1.0.4.0/22
5413|1.0.0.0/16
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Pretty simple with grep/egrep. What are you stuck on?

Comment: I tried to do it with grep -v , but how can I define it will only work in the first field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your pattern to match only on the first field you have to anchor the expression to the start of the line:

```
grep -v -E '^(3549|2152|4701)\|'
```

The `^` marks the beginning of the line (and `$` would mark the end of the line)

The `-E` activates enhanced regular expressions so you don't have to `\` escape pipes and parentheses, and the -v inverses the search (returning only lines that do *not* match).

The ^ matches the start of the line then parentheses with the pipe symbol marks alternatives (3549, 2152 or 4701), and `\|` stands for the pipe symbol itself which your first field ends with, and needs to be escaped by the backslash so it's not treated as another alternation.

Be careful to use single quotes around it because otherwise the shell itself will interpret some of the special characters.